# Moving MySQL data to another drive

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I want to move my data in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data` to `E:\Mysql5Data`

1. Stopped MySQL5 Service
2. Changed "datadir" value in `my.ini` file to `E:/Mysql5Data`
3. Started MySQL5 Service

I got `1067 Process terminated unexpectedly` error while starting MySQL.

Update:

Logs

```
160509 13:18:56 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\DGNLWEBBIP01.lower-test
160509 13:18:56 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\DGNLWEBBIP01.lower-test
160509 13:18:56 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160509 13:18:56 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160509 13:18:56 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
160509 13:18:56 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160509 13:18:56 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160509 13:18:56 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160509 13:18:56  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

SOLUTION:

[Murray's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24403/change-existing-datadir-path/24437#comment253420_24437)

Comment: Any log information that might help? Output from `mysqld --user=mysql --verbose`?

Comment: @Cynical logs are added

Comment: you can Check Mysql5Data folder is owned by mysql ?

Comment: [This comment solved my problem](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24403/change-existing-datadir-path/24437#comment253420_24437)